# can a javascript synchronous function be called concurrently

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function that calls a synchronous function inside it. The asynchronous might be called concurrently, will the synchronous function in it cause any problems?

Can synchronous functions work concurrently calculating something for both callers at the same time? Or when the function is called, it waits for the previous call to finish?

Comment: If sync function is inside async one, you will have 2 async functions.
So they must work concurently.

Comment: node is single threaded

Comment: Asynchronous in javascript isn't the same as parallel. So no it want cause any problems, because it will always wait for the previous call to finish. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: When you say "asynchronous function", what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean declared with the `async` keyword?  Or do you just mean a function that contains an asynchronous operation?  If you include a code example, we could answer you a lot more specifically.

Comment: @marko how can I make it so that two callers of a function use the same function in parallel without waiting for completion?

Comment: @jfriend00 I mean a function that is called at a huge rate. It is called more than once every second. And in it, there is a synchronous function. I want to make it so that that syncronous function catches up with the speed of calling the asynchronous function

Comment: @Mr.Blockchain you could use this module to call two functions in parallel https://github.com/feross/run-parallel

Comment: @Mr.Blockchain - as described in answer by CertainPerformance, the asynchronous function does NOT work concurrenly. (unless you create workers there, then they can use thread pool in background, but every other code you write is run with one thread and only one piece of code is executed by event loop in any given moment)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "synchronous function catches up with speed of calling the asynchronous function".  We need to see actual code to really understand what you're talking about.  You can't speed up things.  You can coordinate when one thing runs relative to another.  Not sure what you're really trying to do.  Please show actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is single-threaded. An asynchronous function doesn't mean that it can't run synchronous code, it just means that it can defer execution when it comes across `await`, and returns a promise. If some code in an asynchronous function calls something synchronous, that synchronous will run to completion before the asynchronous function continues - just like in a normal function.

Comment: Well explained sir :)

Comment: How can I make both the async and the sync func inside it not wait for a previous call? I want the code inside my async function to be executed once it is called, even if the previous call was 0.002 seconds ago and it is still executing.

Comment: @Mr.Blockchain, you can't interrupt the current thread like that - you just have to call the function you want like normal, and it'll be executed once the stack gets to it.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronous functions inside the asynchronous function should not be a problem if you want to run them concurrently, take as example:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("First"),4000);
setTimeout(() => console.log("Second"),1000);
```

These two will execute in the specified order, but the functions inside will run when their containing function lets them do so, thus the output in console will be:

```
Second
First
```